# All questions highlighted when viewing favourited tag questions on mobile version

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, mobile-web, tag-highlighting

If I view questions for one of my favourite tags, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) on the mobile version of the site I get a Simpsons themed version (every question is highlighted yellow).

Please highlight only questions with other favourite tags as the main site does (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Favorite tags won't be highlighted on mobile if you're looking at a list of questions by those tags.

Comment: Has the next deploy happened yet? I still see this behavior today.

Comment: @Rob yes, you shouldn't see this anymore.  Note that highlighting is only suppressed for a favorite tag if you're looking at a list of questions with that tag explicitly.  If you're viewing a list and it just so happens they all have that tag, they'll still get highlighted.  Basically if you [go here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) & have [tag:winapi] favorited you won't get highlighting for [tag:winapi], but everywhere else you still will.

Comment: Nonetheless, I still see it. It's a little more nuanced, though, since it has something to do with the tag name. I've opened [a new bug about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144475/33732).