# Mobile pages for favorite tags highlight all questions when a plus sign is in the tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, mobile-web, tag-highlighting

Two tags I follow are [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi). When viewed on my phone, all the questions on the C++ tag page appear highlighted as they would on any other page. The questions on the Delphi tag page, on the other hand, are highlighted the way they're supposed to be: Instead of *all* the questions, only questions tagged with *another* of my favorite tags are highlighted.

The [com+](/questions/tagged/com%2b) and [llvm-c++-api](/questions/tagged/llvm-c%2b%2b-api) tags exhibit the same bug, so I think it has something to do with the tag containing the `+` character.

This seems like a more specific version of a previously fixed bug, [All questions highlighted when viewing favourited tag questions on mobile version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128237/33732).

Comment: Interesting. The initialization code for the highlighting gets passed the tag name with all of the plus signs removed, so the exclusion matching fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, encoding bug in the suppress list as Tim pointed out.